# Is It Necessary to Set Pointers to nil in Objective-C After release?

Tags: objective-c, null

Is there anything wrong with doing something like

> `NSString * string = [ [ NSString alloc ] init ];`
>   `...`
>   `[ string release ];`

or is there any value (other than best practice) in also adding

> `string = nil;`

?

Comment: Setting to nil makes NSZombieEnabled useless I guess, so might be counterproductive. It would be better if someone more knowledgeable than me explained this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not necessary, but good practice.  If you were to inadvertently reference it after release, bad things could happen, but in Objective C there isn't any harm in referencing a nil.

Comment: Cool. I figured as much, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't something crucial I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Setting an instance variable to nil is more useful in a multi-threaded application than a single-threaded one, since with multiple threads you can't always guarantee that an instance variable will only be read *before* it's released.

I generally don't bother in single-threaded applications, unless there's some other compelling reason.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is really the same as C with a fancy preprocessor.

Setting a pointer to nil in Objective-C has no effect on what was once pointed to by that pointer.