# UIView and memory management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

A beginners question about how to be memory efficient when using an UIView which contains a couple of images (ca. 500K). I guess if I handle this in the wrong way and call this view ten or twenty times, my app will crash (as I have leaked about 5-10 MB of RAM).

I have an UIView which I create programatically like so:

```
myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:0,0,0,0];
```

To this view I add a couple of images so that it eats up 500K of memory. After I'm done with this view, I'd like to free up the memory again. So I coded:

```
[myView removeFromSuperview];
myView = nil;
[myView release];
```

Is this the way to go? I am particularly uncertain about the last release call. Is myView not already released if I remove it from my superview and set it to nil?

Also, would it be a good idea to simply autorelease myView in the first instance, i.e.

```
myView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:0,0,0,0] autorelease];
```

I'd be grateful for any suggestions and corrections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re sending a `release` message to `nil`. The correct order for those statements would be:

```
[myView removeFromSuperview];
[myView release];
```

and optionally after that:

```
myView = nil;
```

For discussion on why to set to `nil`:

- [Set pointers to nil after release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418999/set-pointers-to-nil-after-release)
- [Is It Necessary to Set Pointers to nil in Objective-C After release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803531/is-it-necessary-to-set-pointers-to-nil-in-objective-c-after-release)
- [What's the difference between setting an object to nil vs. sending it a release message in dealloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212628/whats-the-difference-between-setting-an-object-to-nil-vs-sending-it-a-release-m)

The superview retains your view when you add it as a subview, and then releases it when you remove it. You still need you release your hold of it. You could use `autorelease` when allocating it, but since you need to hold on to a pointer to it to be able to send `removeFromSuperview`, the correct way is to send `release` when you are done with that pointer (and then set that pointer to `nil`).

Answer (score 2):

If you set your view to `nil` before you call `release`, you will leak the view and then send a message to nil. First you must release the view:

```
[myView removeFromSuperview];
[myView release];
```

Then you can set your variable to `nil` to avoid sending a message to a deallocated instance.

Answer (score 1):

About the autorelease, I think it's just a matter of personal preference, but I find it much easier to track memory issues when doing:

```
myView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:0,0,0,0] autorelease];
// add myView to wherever it belongs
.....
[myView removeFromSuperview];
myView = nil;
```

As others have pointed out, settting to `myView` to `nil` before you call `release` is incorrect and will leak memory.